# Getting user attributes from Cognito for Pre token generation lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I'm writing a lambda to customize the claims on the accessToken before the token is generated. I need to call an external API with data from my Cognito user pool to get information to customize the claim. This lambda would be triggered before sign in. How do I get a specific field for a particular user from the pool?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd also like to know this.